# Measure download volume from a service provider

Tags: networking, router, snmp

I have an internet service provider that uses satellites. I need to measure the actual download volume for specified time periods. My reading on this lead me to believe that SNMP will do this. Thus I looked for software to install on my ASUS router.

I found Merlin firmware for the RT-AC68U. This changes the firmware in my router and gives it SNMP capabilities. I set up the SNMP on the router. This is straight forward.

I am not able to understand how to get the measurements started or read them when I need to see the download volume over a specified time frame. How do I find those files and read them? How do I know that I have set up SNMP properly?